# Laravel/Eloquent BelongsToMany and globalScopes

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many, eloquent-relationship, laravel-10

In short - I would like to define global scope that would filter related instances by the value of the field in pivot table.
I have defined the next relationship:

```
class Client extends Model {
    function promotions():BelongsToMany{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Promotion::class)
                    ->using(ClientPromotionPivot::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Promotion extends Model {
        // ...
}
```

```
class ClientPromotionPivotextends Pivot {
        protected $casts = [
                'active' => 'boolean'
        ];
}
```

My idea is that by default, everywhare where I access $client->promotions - only active ones would appear:

```
$active_promotions = $client->promotions;
```

BUT, sometimes I need to access them all:

```
$all_promotions = $client->promotions()
            ->withoutGlobalScope('active_promotions') // or something similar
            ->get();
```

Also I have many more similar relationships in many models where the Pivot table has the field active to be filtered on.
The problem is it seems that global scopes doesn't know anything about the pivot table.

P.S. : Please do not offer creating two separated relations - like all_promotions and active_promotions - I would like to avoid this. Also I don't want to write something similar to $client->promotions()->wherePivot('active') everywhere I access promotions.

To me it looks like a missing feature in Eloquent/Laravel. I found this Issue published recently, but there is no solution to it:  https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/48617

What I tried:

1. Defining two different relationships (This is my current solution, but I don't like it too much):

   ```
   function all_promotions():BelongsToMany{
       return $this->belongsToMany(Promotion::class)
                   ->using(ClientPromotionPivot::class);
   }
   function active_promotions():BelongsToMany{
       return $this->all_promotions->wherePivot('active');
   }
   ```
2. Defining conditional relationship:

   ```
   function promotions($active=true):BelongsToMany{
       $relationship = $this->belongsToMany(Promotion::class)
                   ->using(ClientPromotionPivot::class);
       if ($active) $relationship->wherePivot('active');
       return $relationship;
   }
   ```
3. Creating a global scope and passing it the relationship object:

   ```
   class ActivePivot implements Scope {

       public $belongs_to_many_query;
       // we need to pass the relationship to constructor to be able to use **qualifyPivotColumn** method
       public function __construct(BelongsToMany $belongs_to_many_query) {
           $this->belongs_to_many_query = $belongs_to_many_query;
       }

       public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model) {
           return $builder->where(
               $this->belongs_to_many_query->qualifyPivotColumn('active'),
               '=',
               'true'
           );
       }
   }
   ```

   And then using it like so:

   ```
   class Client extends Model {
       function promotions():BelongsToMany{
           $relationship = $this->belongsToMany(Promotion::class)
                       ->using(ClientPromotionPivot::class);
           // Here I'm passing the relationship to the constructor of the global scope
           $relationship->withGlobalScope('active_pivot', new ActivePivot($relationship));
           return $relationship;
       }
   }
   ```

   And this way I can efectively do both:

   ```
   $active_promotions = $client->promotions;
   // and
   $all_promotions = $client->promotions()->withoutGlobalScope('active_pivot');
   ```

All three solutions work... but look ugly and not very flexible (imagine if i'd like to apply multiple global scopes/filters). Intuitively it seems to me that there should be a better approach to it.

Comment: That is why you have a function that encapsulate repeated code so you will not use wherePivote on any other classes, so I think you'll not accept other approaches and that lead us to "Over thinking or Over engineering" !

Comment: @PsyLogic As I said - I have many more similar relationships with similar requirements. And using global scopes (or something similar) approach, I would avoid a lot of code repetition. Just some additional examples - Product->pivot(active)->Provider, Product->pivot(active)->Service, User->pivot(active)->Group... Also it is not everything about "active" - there are some other common filters used by different models and some of them may be combined.

Comment: i think it's a bad idea to put a scope on a relation, or if you really want to do that, name the relation something else that's not confusing, like activePromotions() or something. That way you keep the standard promotions() relation and don't need to rely on withoutGlobalScope, you simply use promotions() or activePromotions() depending on what you need and it's stays clear to someone reading your code. Because another dev will not expect a scope to be applied to the promotions() relation.

Comment: @Lk77 I understand your point of view, but as in 90% of cases we need this filter to be applied and only in admin page we need them to be visible - it is much-much worse if some new developer will forget to add this filter, and clients on the frontend will see things they are not supposed to see, then if the dev will forget to "disable" the filter and somewhere in admin-backend something would not appear... Also, as I said, currently we are using the same solution you suggest, but willing to improve it.
Currently I'm not asking "should I o not", but "how can I" question. Thank you in any case

Comment: @dmikam the issue is, you already listed the available options. The only option you did not list is : `->promotions()->withGlobalScope()` but i don't think it suits your needs. For me the code you are currently using is the best you can get, even using a local scope will not improve anything. Global scopes are not really flexible, conditionnally applying them is never fully clean

Comment: @Lk77 Yes, but this "weird" definition of the global scope, with $belongs_to_many_query in the constructor I came up with looks awkward and unreliable (for example if constructor definition changes for Scopes), kind of an undocumented feature - I am just asking for a "cleaner" solution if such exists.

Comment: @dmikam it's clearly an unsupported feature, global scopes don't work with pivot out of the box, so i don't see a better approach. I do find your approach rather clean however. It's indeed prone to issues if the base class change, you could use something else than construct, like `setPivotRelation`, and do `(new ActivePivot())->setPivotRelation($pivot)` or something like that, it's less prone to errors in case of __construct changes in the base class but it's not perfectly clean

Comment: Ohh, right, I like this approach more than using a constructor! Thanks!